# Are SOAP web services vulnerable to CSRF attacks?

Tags: web-services, soap, csrf, spring-ws, csrf-protection

We have a web application in Spring MVC and also the web services are implemented using Spring Web Service. They are SOAP based. 
I have couple of queries in CSRF front.

1. If there is a CSRF vulnerability for SOAP based web services? I dont think it should be as SOAP is XML. But still not sure if I am missing out on any thing.
2. If there is CSRF vulnerability for SOAP based web service, then how can a incoming request be validated? As for CSRF the token is once generated by the server and then the client (usually browser) send that token again to the server. How is this possible with web service calls.

Any inputs on this will be a help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your Web service perform authentication on the received requests?

Comment: We get the userid and pwd in the soap header which we validate.

Comment: Then your answer is no. If an attacker attempted to send a cross site request to your domain, they would not know the userid and pwd values in order to forge the request.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. Yah so if we are using userid and pwd to validate the request then CSRF attack wont the possible. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @user1630693 Consider putting that detail into the question. Otherwise it is wider (and as such unanswered).

Answer (score 0):

If the SOAP service authenticates requests using user ID and password sent in the SOAP header, then it will not be vulnerable to CSRF attacks. Note however that if that service is used by a Web application, then the Web application itself may still be vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you are authenticating bys somehting that will be sent by the client / User Agent / Browser automatically - such as a Cookie or NTLM / Kerberos token.

In this case an attacker could host a website that posts soap to your application and confince the user to visit it.  The friendly browser would just punt the Cookie in with the request (or automatically authenticate with windows if set in browser/site).